# Receiving null value for ref hook forwarding when used with redux compose

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to pass `useRef` details from parent component to child component.

It works if child is a basic component as follows.

```
const Apple = React.forwardRef(({
}, ref) => {
    console.log(`Apple ref: ${ref}`); // can print value, ref not null 
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {`ref is: ${ref && ref.current}`}
    </div>
  );
});

export default Apple;
```

But if I use redux and use compose to wrap the component as follows, the ref ends up as null.

How could I fix this?

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const Apple = React.forwardRef(({
  p1,
  p2,
  p3,
}, ref) => {
  console.log(`Apple ref: ${ref}`); // no longer working, ref prints null.
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {`ref is: ${ref && ref.current}`}
    </div>
  );
});

const mapStateToProps = someFunction({
  state: getState,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  a: a1,
  b: a2,
  c: a3,
};

const chainUp = compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
);

export default chainUp(Apple);
```

Comment: You'll want to specify `forwardRef: true` in the [options object for `connect(..)`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object)

Comment: @motto Thanks. Updated to connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { forwardRef: true }) but same outcome as null for ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you probably should not be using `withRouter` or `connect` in a modern React application.
Those HOCs are necessary for backwards compatibility with legacy class components, but in a function component you can (and should!) just use `useRouter`, `useSelector` and `useDispatch`.